# Modifying a pdf using Hummus and creating buffer

Tags: node.js, hummus.js

I'm modifying a pdf using the code below but struggling with how to create a buffer that can then be used as an email attachment without writing anything to disk.

I'm finding it hard to work out from the documentation.

```
    var pdfWriter = hummus.createWriterToModify(__dirname + '/voucher.pdf', needToCreateBuffer);

    var pageModifier = new hummus.PDFPageModifier(pdfWriter, 0);
    var fontOswald = pdfWriter.getFontForFile('.fonts/Oswald-Bold.ttf');
    pageModifier.startContext()
        .getContext()
        .writeText(
            '£100',
            296, 105, {
                font: fontOswald,
                size: 70,
                colorspace: 'gray',
                color: 0x00
            }
        ).writeText(
            'CODE: GHGJHJHH',
            296, 80, {
                font: fontOswald,
                size: 18,
                colorspace: 'gray',
                color: 0x00
            }
        );
    pageModifier.endContext().writePage();
    pdfWriter.end();
```

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to you problem? Can you shed some light on how you solved it?

Comment: @dottodot did you manage to solve your problem ? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

you can take look [here](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki/Custom-streams#available-streams).
use streams creating buffer.

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks